# Composer - Downloading git repos that don't have composer.json

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, composer-php

I'm trying to use composer in Symfony 2.1 to pull down vendors from github libraries that are not composer aware and probably never will be.

For examples:
Old Deps file:

```
[jQuery]
git=git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git
version=1.8.1

[Mocha]
git=https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha.git
```

Composer (doesn't work)

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "jquery",
            "version": "1.8.1",
            "dist": {
                "url": "git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git",
                "type": "git"
            }
        }
    }
],
"require": {
    "jquery": "1.8.1"
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are downloading from git, you need to specify a "source" package, not a "dist" package. Use:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "jquery",
            "version": "1.8.1",
            "source": {
                "url": "git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "1.8.1"
            }
        }
    }
],
"require": {
    "jquery": "1.8.1"
}
```

Comment: If there aren't tags defined on the repo use "reference":"master" above.

Comment: as I got problems with pubkey permission, https works fine for me:
    "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com:/angular/angular.js.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "v1.1.5"
                }

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use`Bower`for front end package management and only use composer for what it was designed for. (PHP packages).

http://bower.io/

Comment: true that, thank for clafying that point, its not always that obvious, looking back it is..  i might add bower to my symfony2 based js heavy app to help separate out the front end..